# How to programmatically open an Office file locate on a Server with c#?

Tags: c#, wcf, vsto

i have a VSTO application(WPF) which can save an opened Excel File on a IIS Server(WCF). I'm planning to use it on different PCs. So i'm trying to implement a function that open a file located on this Server. But it seems very difficult to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in that way. Get the file content from the server as string or byte and save it to some temporary location. The you can use the Workbooks.Open method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx

[EDIT]
I have found something useful for you I think. Take a look at this
[Managing Documents on a Server by Using the ServerDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772073.aspx)

Comment: Thank u for the feedback! i try to use it if this feed my needs!

Comment: Thanks lszk! i found that one too! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3k79a5x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx